# rxjs6 doesn't pass value within promise in pipe

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a piece of code like this:

```
source$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(input => ajaxPost1(input)), // ajaxPost1 returns ajaxObservable
    tap(console.log), // can print HTTP response
    exhaustMap(({result}) => ajaxPost2(result)), // ajaxPost2 returns promise
    tap(console.log), // print nothing sometimes even if promise has been resolved and I don't know why
)
.subscribe(...);
```

and `ajaxPost2` is actually a function named `handlePrecheck` like this:

```
handlePrecheck(precheckResponse) {
    const {response, request} = precheckResponse;

    if (!response.status) {
        this.displayInfo(response.msg);
        return Promise.resolve(null);
    }

    // 早退时，签到流程是否继续由UI决定
    if (response.isEarlyCheckout) {
        // const a = this.confirmEarlyCheckout(precheckResponse);
        // window.a = a;
        // console.log(a);
        // return a;
        return this.confirmEarlyCheckout(precheckResponse);
    }

    if (response.holidayToCancel && response.holidayToCancel.id) {
        const {id, duration} = response.holidayToCancel

        this.confirmCancelHoliday(request.body.get('picture'), duration, id);
        // 当有假期时总是终止签到过程
        return Promise.resolve(null);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(precheckResponse);
}
```

And `this.confirmEarlyCheckout` is a method which return a promise which will be resolved soon according to UI event(I can confirm this by checking that promise object in dev tool) .

`handlePrecheck` won't pass value to down-stream only when it enters `if(response.isEarlyCheckout)` branch, but works well when it enters other branches and returns promise.

Very appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include the text of your code *directly in the question*, rather than as a attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I have find out the reason...I unsubscribe the `source$` when waiting for UI event to resolve Promise, so the resolved value of Promise won't be passed to down-stream